# Is this grammatically correct? "Us with You"

Tags: grammar, slogan, italian

Is this slogan correct?:

> "Us with You"
>   "With You To Win Every Challenge"

It's from an Italian website translated to English.

Sounds a little strange to me.

Comment: Headlines do not follow normal English rules.

Comment: What's the problem? You don't need to create a complete sentence here. It's like labelling a photograph *“Me with my dog”*.

Answer (score 1):

Both the quoted fragments are grammatically defective, in the strict sense that they are not complete sentences - they [lack a subject and verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212822/sentences-with-no-verb). However, it is accepted practice for advertising slogans to consist of a short phrase, where the subject, object or verb is implied by the context, or deliberately ambiguous.

> [*A well known fried chicken brand is*] **finger lickin' good**.
>
> [*There are*] **3 million** [*unit's of a soft drink sold*] **a day**.

In general, it is considered OK, [or even good style](https://nastyguide.wordpress.com/2012/02/22/sentences-without-verbs/), to miss out part of a sentence - if the missing part can be inferred in context.

I think this applies to the latter phrase, but not the former. The second one can clearly be understood as:

> We Are With You To Win Every Challenge.

(* the capitalisation of every word is [acceptable in a slogan or motto](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/289679/should-you-use-first-word-capitals-for-an-advertising-slogan-used-in-a-descripti). ** 'win' is an awkward verb to go with *challenge*. 'Beat', 'tackle' or 'overcome' would be normal.)

***However***, "Us with you" is more problematic. The obvious interpretation is, "**we are with you**" (in which case, "We With You" would be a better translation). I guess there has been a machine translation of the Italian word **noi**, which can mean either *we* or *us*.

I imagine there are some rare contexts where "Us With You" forms part of a grammatical sentence, that could be meaningfully shortened thus into a slogan. But I can't think of a good example. If a company wanted to show that it provides its service in collaboration with its customer - "Our service is provided by us, with your help" - I'd expect a preposition before *us* in the slogan: "***By Us With You***".